# Calculate value based on displayed value not actual value

Tags: excel

I have the following formula in cell C18

=C16*C19/10

Cell C16 contains the value 2.37 and Cell C19 contains the value 80.

Cell C18 displays the value as 19.0, but the actual value is 18.96. So excel is rounding.

I need to perform the calculation of taking =E18/C18*100. Where E18 contains the value 2.0.

Currently, when I calculate  =E18/C18*100 I am getting 10.5485 because excel is calculating based on the actual value, but I need the calculation to be performed on the displayed value of 19.0. So I need the calculation to display 10.5263.

Does anyone know how I might get the calculation to render based on the displayed value and not the actual value? Thanks!

Comment: use `ROUND` to round the value to the same precision as you have set for the display.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding the value was the correct answer.

=ROUND(C16*C19/10,1)

Another example -

=ROUND(C17/(C16*C19)*1000,1)

Comment: This is barely a comment. Show the function applied to the situation.